# How to get the server IP Address (in C# / asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a 1 line method to get the IP Address of the server?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean "server" - ASP.Net processing machine or server-side firewall/gate/proxy

Comment: You need to take into account that there can be many IP addresses assigned to your server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/646525/292060, even though this has a better selected answer.

Comment: I would love to see how to proceed when you have to rely on a `HttpRequestMessage` object instead of the classic `HttpRequest`.

Comment: @SandRock - you could take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/MikeJansen/2653453) which looks for the `MS_HttpContext` property and then casts to an `HttpContextBase` which would allow access to the `ServerVariables` property. Depending on where you're doing this, you may also be able to grab the HttpContext directly and query that as `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]` (sorry for the late reply ;))

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

From the [docs](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=52471):

> Returns the server address on which the request came in. This is important on computers where there can be multiple IP addresses bound to the computer, and you want to find out which address the request used.

This is distinct from the Remote addresses which relate to the client machine.

Comment: Yep, lots of handing things hiding in the ServerVariables collection.

Comment: Perfect answer - from old ASP Classic days , I should have remembered this one :)

Comment: Slight glitch: When hitting the server from a browser on the server, it resolves to 127.0.0.1.  Otherwise, love it.

Comment: @Allbite - That possibly depends on how the DNS on the server is configured, or how you request the site - for example if there's a HOSTS entry pointing the domain to 127.0.0.1 to ensure that you browse just the local server (in a load balanced environment for example), or you request the site as LocalHost, then yes, you'll definitely get 127.0.0.1 back. I've had other sites that reported the correct IP address for the browser when they've gone via a proper DNS lookup.

Comment: This shows the address of the server that sent the request
NOT
The server that is hosting the website

Comment: @Talha - Nope, `LOCAL_ADDR` returns the network address associated with the hosted instance of the site - `REMOTE_ADDR` returns the address of the requesting client: "`REMOTE_ADDR`
The IP address of the remote host that is making the request."

Answer (score 6):

From searching the net I found following code: (I couldn't find a single line method there)

```
string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

// Show the hostname 

MessageBox.Show(myHost);

// Get the IP from the host name

string myIP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[index].ToString();

// Show the IP 

MessageBox.Show(myIP);
```

-> where **index** is the index of your ip address host (ie. network connection).

Code from: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial149_Get-the-IP-address-in-a-Windows-application.html

Comment: "where index is the index of your ip address host (ie. network connection)." - What does this mean? That link no longer works

Answer (score 2):

As other(s) have posted, [`System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) is the way to go. When you access the `AddressList` property, you'll want to take the [`AddressFamily`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily.aspx) property into account, as it could return both IPv4 AND IPv6 results.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return your machine public IP address when run this code on your PC and when you deploy your application on server will return Server IP address.

```
public static string Getpublicip()
    {
        try
        {
            string externalIP = "";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://icanhazip.com.ipaddress.com/");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            externalIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
            return externalIP;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return "null";
        }

    }
```