# discover server ip address throw the network scanning

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discover server ip address through the network scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018561/discover-server-ip-address-through-the-network-scanning)

I'm going to develop client server application in c#.

The clients must be able to discover server ip address. How is this possible through network discovery?

Any help and soloution on this could be very usefull, and if there is some sample code it would be much better!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting the IP address of server in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646525/getting-the-ip-address-of-server-in-asp-net)

sorry I should have put this as a dup and removed my initial answer.