# Discover server ip address through the network scanning

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

i'm going to develop C# client-server application, and i need to tell the clients what is the server's ip address it could be happen from client or from server broadcasting.

any help and soloution on this could be very usefull, and if there is some sample code it would be much better!

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, are you talking about server discovery? That is client doesn't know the address of the server in advance (neither its hostname nor its IP address) so you need means on the client to figure that out somehow?

Comment: Yes exacly i'm talking about server discovery!!! i need tell the clients whats the server ip!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can broadcast using BroadCast method
here a project that shows you how to do it:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C

Comment: unfortunatly You Did not undrastand the Question!