# How to get ip address of the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, ip-address

how can I get the ip address of the IIS box where an asp.net application is running on? I tried:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Check if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646525/getting-the-ip-address-of-server-in-asp-net) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp) are all the variables:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress; should work
```

[Link 1](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB32_How-do-I-get-the-visitors-IP-address.html)